# onFocusChange of EditText never called

Tags: android, android-layout

I like to detect user's focus on the EditText using

```
IDEditTxt.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
               Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                ((EditText) v).getId() + " has focus - " + hasFocus,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
       });
```

But when I set the cursor on it, onFocusChange is never get called. When I research, found that EditText xml should have

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:focusable="true"
```

So I put these two lines in the EditText's xml, but still not called.
My intention is if the user focus on the EditText, I like to display the AlertDialog rather than keyboard, so that user's choice on the dialog will be displayed on the EditText. How can I implement that? Where can I have similar program for that implementation?
Thanks

Comment: so toast is not shown?

Comment: @Sajmon yes toast is not shown

Comment: and error is thrown? or not?

Comment: no error thrown, does not go inside the onFocusChange

Comment: try instead of creating anonymous class create Activity that implements OnFocusChangeListener so `YourActivity implements OnFocusChangeListener` and then assign it to `yourEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(this)`

Comment: I make a new EditText and tried again. New EditText worked. I need to check what is the difference. How can i disable the keyboard? Thanks

Comment: +Sajmon , I have the same issue as Bryanyan, can you please help me by answering this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38341339/cancelling-event-due-to-no-window-focus-motionevent